# autofs 'failed to mount autofs path' as service but not manually (selinux)

Tags: centos, selinux, autofs, automounting

I'm on CentOS 6.6 and I'm having a strange problem with `autofs`.

I'm trying to mount an `smb` share on `/var/www/html/mysite/docfolder`, so I created a `docfolder` inside the `mysite` folder, ran `chmod 777` on it, then added:

```
/var/www/html/mysite/docfolder /etc/auto.docfolder --ghost
```

in /etc/auto.master . Then i created auto.docfolder under /etc and inside it:

```
pdf -fstype=cifs,rw,noperm,user=username,pass=password ://myshare/docs
```

When I run

```
sudo /sbin/service autofs restart
```

inside `/var/log/messages` I can read:

```
Jun 18 12:19:53 Rtmbssrv automount[30779]: do_mount_autofs_indirect: failed to mount autofs path /var/www/html/mysite/docfolder at /var/www/html/mysite/docfolder
Jun 18 12:19:53 Rtmbssrv automount[30779]: handle_mounts: mount of /var/www/html/mysite/docfolder failed!
```

So I tried stopping the service and running it manually:

```
sudo automount -vdf
```

And the folder got mounted correctly without errors.

Changing the mount folder to: `/mnt/docfolder` works correctly every time.

What's the difference of running `automount` instead of launching `autofs` as service?

Why is the service unable to mount that folder?

Edit:
It's a SELinux related problem. I have to keep it enabled, so now the question is: how to give permission to autofs to mount file inside a apache folder, leaving it readable from the apache server?

Comment: FWIW some services have trouble plainly restarting (for various reasons), but work fine with a `stop; wait a bit; start` sequence, autofs might be one of them. Also check if when executed as a service it is running with the same args.

Comment: Args are the same (I double checked it). I also tryed to wait about 5/10 minutes. No way. I think it's a selinux related problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this in my notes, from when I ran into this same thing:

---

Set SELinux boolean to allow Apache to access CIFS shares:

```
# setsebool -P httpd_use_cifs on
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that Derek give the right answer. Anyway I also got that working with:

```
 sudo mkdir /var/wwww/html/site/pdf
 sudo chmod 755 /var/wwww/html/site/pdf

 #try to change SElinux folder tipe
 sudo chcon -t public_content_rw_t /var/www/html/site/pdf

 #i want that persistent
 sudo semanage fcontext -a -t

 #add this inside fcontext file
 public_content_rw_t "/var/www/html/site/pdf(/.*)?"

 #se if the change is definitive
 restorecon -Rv /var/www/html/site/pdf
```